# SQL select statement over a relative time range?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My SQL Server table has a trigger that enters the current date and time into a `DATETIME` column (let's call it `last_updated`). I would like to run a query that selects all records in the table with a `last_updated` value from within the past hour. How can I specify a relative time range in my query that only selects records updated in the past hour?

Comment: wouldn't that be as straight forward as Select * from your table where last_updated >= dateadd(hour,-1,getdate())  or am I missing something?

Comment: For future reference, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider that the expectation here is that you do some research, have a go, and post a question only when you get stuck.

Comment: @DaleK understood, I had done some research of my own but somehow had missed the DATEADD function suggested in one of the other responses. I'll be a bit more diligent before I post in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like

```
SELECT <Columns>
FROM <Table Name>
WHERE last_updated <= GETDATE()
      AND
      last_updated >= DATEADD(Hour, -1, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Cool, TIME was unnecessary. While strictly correct, there's not really any need for the `<= GETDATE()` clause unless the trigger could post updated times in the future.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. I guess my own research wasn't quite thorough enough to find the DATEADD function.